# Call to undefined function get_translations_for_domain() Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I upgraded my Wordpress from 5.0.2 to 5.8.1 and in doing so, I cam across this error whenever I try and load a page `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_translations_for_domain() in /var/www/vhosts/site/html/blog/wp-includes/l10n.php`

I can't find anything on this error. The admin panel still works, the error only shows up on the frontend page.

Comment: Turn on debugging and check the stack trace for who is originating that call. Do you have any caching plugins installed?

Comment: It's strange, because the function should be defined in the same file at [Line 1306](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.8/src/wp-includes/l10n.php#L1306). Maybe it was truncated during the upgrade process?

Comment: Maybe reinstall the latest version.